# Signing messages in cpp

Tags: signature, cpp-ethereum, secp256k1

I am trying to execute eth transactions from cpp. For that we need to be able to sign messages using Elliptic curve algorithm. I have found [this](https://github.com/bitcoin-core/secp256k1) repo, but output signature is different from what we get from ethers library. My input to secp256k1 library is hashed message.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [libethc's source code](https://github.com/mhw0/libethc/blob/a4eb00099fa80660ce8e80eacfb195d0f7e3df78/src/ecdsa.c#L31). You have to build it with `--enable-module-recovery` to enable recovery module (and it's turned off by default). Otherwise you will not get the desired result.

Here's an example if you're trying to sign a legacy transaction: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/150569/121459